# Historic Azure Map data

Tags: azure-maps

My company is interested in using azure Maps for traffic data. Data related to the traffic density surrounding to the garage location. Keeping the garage location in the center we are trying to find what's the traffic flow (is it heavy traffic, light traffic, road closed, traffic jam etc) and also we are trying to find the speed limit of each road. My question is, does anyone know if Azure Maps can provide this information?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the outcome of your own research so far?

Comment: So far, there is no historical data.  Our Data Engineers couldn't find any historical data. Only current info. If we start collecting the data now, then eventually we will have historic data.  But our business customer may want data from 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Historical traffic data is not currently available in Azure Maps. However this is something that we are investigating as a potential future feature.

Real-time traffic data is available. Details on all the traffic services can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/traffic The traffic flow segment sounds like it might be what you are looking for. The vector tiles could also be used and would be more efficient if you needed to analyze a large number of roads/large area, but would be more dev work. The flow data has a free flow speed with is not the speed limit, but the speed traffic generally travels at (usually close to the speed limit). The actual speed limit data can be retrieved using the reverse geocoding service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressreverse Be sure to set the returnSpeedLimit option.